# Binding datagridviewcomboboxcolumn to datagridviewtextboxcolumn

Tags: c#, binding, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I would like to do the following in the best possible efficient way:

Imagine I have 2 datagridviews, let's say, **dgv1** and **dgv2**.

- **dgv1** has some columns, and one of the columns is of type: *datagridviewTEXTBOXcolumn*.
- **dgv2** also has some columns, and one of the columns is of type *datagridviewCOMBOBOXcolumn*.

The columns for the datagridviews are created in design time.

In run-time I want to populate the *datagridviewCOMBOBOXcolumn* in **dgv2** from *datagridviewTEXTBOXcolumn* in **dgv1** by taken into account the following cases:

1. **dgv1** in some cases is cleared and new items are added (row by
   row)
2. **dgv1**, depending on the case, sometimes is updated with new rows (added to the existing ones).
3. Some cells of *datagridviewTEXTBOXcolumn* in **dgv1** can change its
   value
4. Some cells of *datagridviewTEXTBOXcolumn* in **dgv1** can have identical values
5. I want to filter the identical values and make them appear only 1 time in *datagridviewCOMBOBOXcolumn* in **dgv2**.
6. Respect each item in *datagridviewCOMBOBOXcolumn* of **dgv2**, I would like to take it the  form: **(tag, datagridviewTEXTBOXcolum item in dgv1)**  but I want tag to be not visible in the combobox. Tag would be a kind of object that permits me to take it into account when item is selected in the combobox and do some stuff.

So how to do this binding efficiently and that *datagridviewCOMBOBOXcolumn* updates automatically by taken into account those cases?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).